# Back up Reporting Server or Reporting Encryption Key TFS 2013?

Tags: sql-server, tfs

Is it better to back up regularly the reporting server or the reporting encryption key in TFS 2013? Do you really only need to back up the key once? I know that you don't need the cube or the warehouse, but for sure you need the configuration and collection databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really only need to backup the key once. You will need it only if you have to restore and only need to refresh it if it changes.

I would recommend that you use the built in backup tool for TFS as most folks don't reply do a backup properly with other tools. Just like Sharepoint with TFS you need to have the databases in sync at the transaction level and tgebobly way to do this is marked transaction logs.

The bonus is that the tool also backs up the encryption key for you.